# how to extract data from a scraped page that doesn't have a lot of structure

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, lxml

I'd like to do some analysis on a post I just read on a baseball stat site.  The page in question is available at http://www.fangraphs.com/blogs/fangraphs-crowd-the-top-47-free-agents/

I'd like to scrape the data that starts with the player's name (with the block image showing what # they are on the list) that is in the paragraph tags below the player's name.  (So not the table data right below.)

An example of the data:

```
#1 Robinson Cano (2B) 
Age PA  BB%     K%       AVG    OBP      SLG    wOBA    wRC+    Off  Def    WAR
30  681 9.5%    12.5%   .314    .383    .516    .384    142     30.6 2.5    6.0

Real Years: 8
Real AAV: $24.5
Real Total: $196.2

Fake Years: 5
Fake AAV: $23.9
Fake Total: $119.7

Representative Comment
“I wouldn’t want to guarantee salary past age 37 or age 38. I could see him getting more years than that, at the same AAV I am willing to pay in fake world.”

[next player in example]...
#2 Jacoby Ellsbury
[etc.]
```

The numbered item (#1) isn't in an OL, but it does have a name attribute on the a tag.  So I can grab that.  unfortunately, the rest of the data doesn't seem to be structured in the html in an easy to get to fashion.

I am looking to extract the data that goes "real years: 8" through "fake total: $119.7".  (Note: some of the other players have different data keys, e.g., "Will accept qualifying offer".  I know what all these keys will be, but not every player has every data entry.)

My strategy was to select the first player in the list, and start to grab sibling elements from there.  If the sibling element's text matches one of my known keys ("Real Years", etc.), then store the numeric value for that.  If the sibling element is an `<a>` element with a name attribute, then I know it's the next player and to go to the next iteration of the loop.

I'm curious how other people would approach this problem.  I feel like my way is clunky, but it's the only approach I can imagine w/o more html structure to the page.

I'm using python and the lxml.html module.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like this is a one time job, and the html isn't nicely formatted for parsing, so you shouldn't put too much effort into writing the perfect parser for this webpage. Quick and dirty is the way to go.

A much easier solution would be to simply copy the page text, paste it into the text editor of your choice, and save it as a plain text file. You can then write a script to parse the text file.

Look for lines which start with '#'. This indicates the start of a new player's section. Then consume those lines until the next player's section starts.

Comment: Agreed that I'm not going to spend too much time on it.  I was just curious, interested in using this as a learning situation.  Your suggestion for a text editor is obvious and brilliant, thanks!